Does subdifferentiability imply convexity?
By the theorem 23.4. on page 217 of Convex Analysis by Rockafellar, a proper convex function $f: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ is subdifferentiable in $\mathrm{ri}\, \mathrm{dom}\, f$. I am now wondering about the converse of this theorem. If a proper function $g: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ is subdifferentiable in $\mathrm{ri}\, \mathrm{dom}\, g$, is it convex?
Edit: The function $g$ satisfies $\mathrm{ri}\, \mathrm{dom}\, g$ is convex.

Why aren't proper convex functions convex a fortiori?

@SassatelliGiulio Sorry, I miswrote. I have edited the post.

What's proper here, preimages of compacts are compact? Don't have Rockafellar on hand.

No, because the relative interior of a domain can be empty if the domain is not convex. Maybe it works if convexity of the domain is added.

@AlvinL The function $f: \mathbb R^d \rightarrow [-\infty, \infty]$ is proper iff. for all $x \in \mathbb R^d$, $f(x) > -\infty$ and there exists $x' \in \mathbb R^d$ such that $f(x) < \infty$.

@grew Oh you're right. I will change the question.

@AlvinL Sorry for the typo, $f(x') < \infty$.

Naïve question: Wouldn't just any differentiable, non-convex function be a counterexample?

For completeness, you should include your definition of subdifferentiability: Usually, it is defined only for convex functions. But maybe you work with generalized subdifferentials...

@HyperbolicPDEfriend I think it wouldn't be, because the gradient is a subgradient only if the function we are considering is a convex function.

Such a function is convex in $ri \ dom \ f$ provided this set is convex. Take $x,y \in ri \ dom \ f$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$. Then $z := \lambda x + (1-\lambda)y \in ri  \ dom \ f$ has non-empty subdifferential by assumption, i.e., there is $g$ such that
$$
\langle g, x-z\rangle \le f(x) - f(z), \ \langle g, y-z\rangle \le f(y) - f(z).
$$
Since $x-z = (1-\lambda)(x-y)$, $y-z=- \lambda (x-y)$, multiplying the inequalities by $\lambda$ and $(1-\lambda)$ and adding them yields to
$$
0 \le \lambda (f(x) - f(z)) + (1-\lambda) (f(y)-f(z)),
$$
and $f$ is convex.
